# Whether to use onPostExecute or runOnUiThread or use a Handler to display list of emails in from my inbox?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm a new newbie in android.

I am trying to display the list of emails from my inbox.

```
 protected Message[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
  messages = m.mails();
  return messages;
 }
```

The above function returns the mail messages.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Message[] messages) {
try {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                Log.d("mailFrom"+i, message.getFrom()[0].toString());
                Log.d("mailSubject"+i, message.getSubject().toString());
                Log.d("mailContent"+i, message.getContent().toString());
            }
        } catch...
}
```

The above function onPostExecute does not O/P the mails. is it because the network is being accessed in the UI thread?
Is there a better way to do it especially accessing the message object?

Any Help would be grateful

Comment: onPostExecute method runs on UI thread only..doInBacckGround() only run on different thread

Answer (score 0):

The method onPostExecute of the AsyncTask runs on the UI thread only. doInBackground runs always out the UI Thread.

Probably your problem is that messages is empty. Can you check?
Do you Add the internet user permission? It's very normal forgive it